# Gitlab dpl issue with ruby version

Tags: ruby, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci, dpl

I have a node app that I am deploying through Gitlab. I am using docker image `node:12.8.0`.

Recently it has been failing deployment with the following error

```
 $ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_DEVELOPMENT_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY --skip-cleanup
 Installing deploy dependencies
 ERROR:  Error installing dpl-heroku:
     faraday requires Ruby version >= 2.4.
 Successfully installed multipart-post-2.1.1
 Successfully installed ruby2_keywords-0.0.2
 /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- dpl/provider/heroku (LoadError)
     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider.rb:93:in `rescue in block in new'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider.rb:68:in `block in new'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider.rb:67:in `new'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:31:in `run'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/dpl-1.10.15/bin/dpl:5:in `'
     from /usr/local/bin/dpl:22:in `load'
     from /usr/local/bin/dpl:22:in `'
 Running after_script
 00:01
 Running after script...
 $ echo "Job - $CI_JOB_NAME ended."
 Job - deploy_development ended.
 Cleaning up file based variables
 00:01
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am unable to install Ruby2.4 through `apt-get install ruby2.4`.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem today in Gitlab CI.

The problem is that Node uses [debian stretch (version 9)](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a8494b1676216bfe274073993016da0c2e0bfcdd/12/stretch/Dockerfile) by default as the base for docker images, at least in the 12.x LTS versions. This version of debian has [Ruby 2.3.3 by default in the repositories](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ruby), which is not supported by Faraday, which requires [a version equal to or greater than 2.4](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#supported-ruby-versions).

What I did was use the 12.x-buster tag (notice the `-buster` at the end of the version tag) and in these images of docker Node uses debian buster (version 10) as a base. This version of debian has [Ruby 2.5.5 repositories by default](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ruby), which allows Faraday to be installed and therefore dpl for heroku works normally.

Comment: Thanks A lot  Sr, I got stuck on this one the entire morning. This always worked, It just stated failing for me like 3 days ago. I guess some update on dpl...

Comment: Struggled with this all night. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you referring to the node:version? I tried using node:12.13.0-buster but still fails with "/usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-2.0.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:230:in `ensure_adapter!': An attempt to run a request with a Faraday::Connection without adapter has been made. (RuntimeError)". Any ideas?

Comment: @JarekOstrowski You may preinstall faraday 1.8.0 before running dpl. This solves same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those running into this issue on travis-ci, I was able to do it by adding a `before_deploy` command to specify the version of faraday to use.

```
...
before_deploy:
  - rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install faraday -v 1.8.0
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: $HEROKU_API_KEY
...
```

More details: https://travis-ci.community/t/heroku-deploy-fails-installing-dpl-heroku-encounters-faraday-error/12563/6?u=hallmanitor